# Are keys for HP ML 150 G6 chassis all the same?

Tags: hp, hardware

Recently we dragged a heavy box next to the HP ML150 G6 Server which had a chassis bezel key sticking out of it. So the bezel key broke in half.

Is it possible to buy just a replacement key or they are all unique to their corresponding bezels doors? All I found on the internet [is just this message on the HP forum](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-Netservers/Bezel-keys-ML-150-G6/td-p/1113857),  that was not answered by anyone.

So are these keys all the same, or do I need to get an exact specific one for our server?

Comment: I'm not aware of anyone who owns every single ML150 G6 - only they would be able to definitively answer this question of course...

Answer (score 1):

How bad is the lock broken? Is the bezel locked? I am guessing it is either locked or needs to be locked soon.

I do not have this server but I fond that these are just smaller desk/cabinet locks.  [Here is a spare parts page for your server](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&objectID=c01711613&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN) These are not the best way to secure a server.

`519731-001` is the part-nubmer for the bezel. According to the description and comments from others, it should include a lock and key.

These locks are `barrel` / `tubular` locks. and typically have a 3-4 digit number stamped on them.  If you just need a replacement and the lock is in tact. Go to [eBay](http://www.ebay.com) and search for key and the number. 
Sometimes you have success at a locksmith.

IF its not locked, remove the lock/cam assembly and bring to a hardware store/locksmith.

Comment: That P/N does include the actual lock - see this; http://www.business-it.ch/shop/img/documents/c01706108.pdf

Comment: the lock is not broken just the key.  I don't really have a need to have server locked, but if not locked the bezel doors keeps flailing around.  I saw the part number before,  but for some reason it is not possible to buy just the lock and key,  you have to buy the entire bezel assembly.  I checked multiple sources including the HP's own parts store.  Take a look at the comment on the HP support board referred above.